# Is there any way in sql query to rank certain value in ordered set of records such that ranking reset after it encounter with different value

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to rank status flag's 'Lapsed' value in such a way that it resets itself after it encounters with any other value and when it again encounter with 'Lapsed', it should again start ranking from 1

i am confused  that how can we do such thing in sql. I tried with analytical functions but no luck

Data looks like this.

```
id      yr_mon  status
-------------------------
1002    201703  New
1002    201704  Retained
1002    201705  Unretained
1002    201706  Lapsed
1002    201707  Lapsed
1002    201708  Reactivated
1002    201709  lapsed
1002    201710  Unretained
1002    201711  Lapsed
1002    201712  Lapsed
1003    201703  New
1003    201704  Retained
1003    201705  Lapsed
1003    201706  Lapsed
1003    201707  Reactivated
1003    201708  Lapsed
1003    201709  Lapsed
1003    201710  Lapsed
```

Output should look like this.

```
id      yr_mon  status    lapsed_months
----------------------------------------
1002    201703  New            0
1002    201704  Retained       0
1002    201705  Unretained     0
1002    201706  Lapsed         1
1002    201707  Lapsed         2
1002    201708  Reactivated    0
1002    201709  lapsed         1
1002    201710  Unretained     0
1002    201711  Lapsed         1
1002    201712  Lapsed         2
1003    201703  New            0
1003    201704  Retained       0
1003    201705  Lapsed         1
1003    201706  Lapsed         2
1003    201707  Reactivated    0
1003    201708  Lapsed         1
1003    201709  Lapsed         2
1003    201710  Lapsed         3
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to generate the RowNumber as below. Please use appropriate Ordering of data as per requirement.

```
SELECT * , @row_num :=IF(`status` = 'Lapsed',@row_num+1,0)AS RowNumber  
FROM 
(
    SELECT 1002 id,201703 yr_mon, 'New' `status` UNION ALL
    SELECT 1002,201704,'Retained' UNION ALL
    SELECT 1002,201705,'Unretained' UNION ALL
    SELECT 1002,201706,'Lapsed' UNION ALL
    SELECT 1002,201707,'Lapsed' UNION ALL
    SELECT 1002,201708,'Reactivated' UNION ALL
    SELECT 1002,201709,'Retained' UNION ALL
    SELECT 1002,201710,'Unretained' UNION ALL
    SELECT 1002,201711,'Lapsed' UNION ALL
    SELECT 1002,201712,'Lapsed' UNION ALL
    SELECT 1003,201801,'New' UNION ALL
    SELECT 1003,201802,'Retained' UNION ALL
    SELECT 1003,201803,'Lapsed' UNION ALL
    SELECT 1003,201804,'Lapsed' UNION ALL
    SELECT 1003,201710,'Lapsed'
)A
```

Output might be (but, in absence of an ORDER BY clause, not guaranteed):

```
id      yr_mon  Status      lapsed_months
1002    201703  New         0
1002    201704  Retained    0
1002    201705  Unretained  0
1002    201706  Lapsed      1
1002    201707  Lapsed      2
1002    201708  Reactivated 0
1002    201709  Retained    0
1002    201710  Unretained  0
1002    201711  Lapsed      1
1002    201712  Lapsed      2
1003    201801  New         0
1003    201802  Retained    0
1003    201803  Lapsed      1
1003    201804  Lapsed      2
1003    201710  Lapsed      3
```

Comment: Thanks, can u explain the syntax you used

Comment: One inline variable @row_num is used and value assigned to that variable considering the value in column `Status`. If the value is 'Lapsed' I just increase the @row_num value by setting @row_num = @row_num+1 and for all other values set the @row_num = 0.

Comment: May i ask please , which database this query is running?

Comment: MySQL, as you tagged,

Answer (score 2):

Since 8.0 MySql supports window functions. Group and number rows within a group

```
with grp as (
 select id, yr_mon, status
  , row_number() over(partition by id order by yr_mon) - row_number() over(partition by id, status order by yr_mon)  grp
 from tlog 
)
select id, yr_mon, status, case status when 'Lapsed' then row_number() over(partition by id, grp order by yr_mon) else 0 end lapsed_months
from grp
order by id, yr_mon;
```

fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2d4fcfa5458096c0f3bf296099660d1c
Note i intentionally put source data in an arbitrary order.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you want this for each `id`.

You just want a cumulative sum of the `'lapsed'` values.  You can express this in MySQL 8+ as:

```
select l.*,
       sum(status = 'lapsed') over (partition by id order by yr_mon) as lapsed_months
from t;
```

In earlier versions, you can use variables like this:

```
select * ,
       (@rn := if(@id = id,
                  if(status = 'lapsed', @rn + 1, @rn),
                  0
                 )
       ) as lapsed_months
from (select t.*
      from t
      order by t.id, t.yr_mon
     ) t cross join
     (select @i := -1, @rn := 1) params;
```